# Data Extract not pulling unsubscribe record

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscribe, data-extract, tracking-extract

I used a logunsubevent request to unsubscribe a subscriber and after that, I looked for this subscriberkey in the _unsubscribe data view. It shows up fine.

I am running data extract with below steps to find out the unsub reason for this subscriber but the record itself not being retrieved.

Data Extract--Tracking Extract with extract fields:
Extract Unsubs
Include Unsub Reason

Am I missing anything?

Comment: are you using a rolling range in your extract, if so I don't believe it pulls today data

Answer (score 0):

In a tracking extract you need to be setting the range "from yesterday until tomorrow" to get "today's" data;

assuming today were feb 18th 2021, set a "custom range", and this is the date range you want to enter to get today's sendouts included:

[image]